# Pivot table Filter deletes other data on sheet

Tags: excel

I currently have a pivot table on one sheet and a list of data on another sheet. I wanted to put both next to each other so I moved the pivot table to the left of the data set without a problem. However, every time I use a filter on the pivot table, it prompts me to ask if I want to delete all the other data on that sheet. Clicking okay clears the whole sheet but clicking cancel doesn't apply the filter. Any idea how I can get around this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The only way around this is to make sure they do not overlap at all ...  because if the pivot expands / contracts it affects the sheet and thus the table. I do think a possible work around at least in my quick testing is too keep the table on another sheet, but create another pivot of that table on the same sheet. Then Simply put the columns as columns so it looks like a table.

Comment: Perhaps I should try putting it on the right side rather than the left so that it has unlimited space to expand... I gave it a ton of room on the left side so that it wouldnt overlap but it still wouldnt let me insert filters. I will keep playing with it. I like your other idea if this were for me but I need the user to be able to change the pivot table and have access to the other table at the same time without having to change sheets (changing sheets creates room for human error). But thanks for the help!